# Total price on the product page before "Add To Cart" button, why not?

Tags: user-expectation, landing-page, prices

**I'm having a hard discussion about adding total price per product in product page before adding to cart or not.**

**The situation:**

Our user normally add more than 1 product to cart and our products have a cheap price, but the user never buys just 1. For example, if he is buying a roof tile, he will add 500 tiles. And considering it I thinking the total price could be a benefit helping users to know the individual total (subtotal for each product) before add to cart reducing the shopping cart abandonment. And the experience could improve because this new feature will reduce the number of page changes and we will be very transparent with the user without bad surprises.

As this feature is no common on other e-commerce is being very difficult to approve an A/B test. **Adding the total price for each product on the product page looks a good idea? Why not?**

*I already read [this topic](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/88785/why-not-have-sub-total-in-product-page-instead-of-checkout) but they are talking something more advanced and my user is not adding a shirt or simple items to the cart. I just want to calculate: Product Price X Quantity and show the total price.*

See an example of how I expect to do it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends the type of online store platform you are working with.

The online store I work for when buying there's a modal showing the quantity (345 in this example) + the unit price and the total:

[image]

When checking the basket too:

[image]

To me is very important to always show the unit price, this is very beneficial in the case of special discounts by quantity. You may have to restructure the price tags to show all possibilities, something that is not easy at all.

Comment: Good answer too, I liked the alternative ide of showing the total price on modal after clicking on add to cart.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you buy wholesale products (50, 100 etc.)
the total price is really helpful

The product can also be grouped and sold into packages (pallets, cartons e.g.)
It is worth highlighting the number of packages (e.g. 1 set - 50 pieces - $ 500 - price)

It is worth asking users whether such facilitation will actually be beneficial for them

in my opinion, empathically, the total price can be useful in calculation (preferably if it would also work dynamically)

Comment: Good answer. We already use tier prices but the user still adding 100 packages.

Comment: @BraDev if you have tier pricing all the more reason to add it. I think tme.eu or digikey.com does it - can't check as I'm on mobile. A nice feature (although not necessarily wanted by business) is cart optimisation - when in cart show that they can lower the price per item when they buy the lowest amount for the next tier (it saved me a couple bucks).